# PHP create folder inside ($_POST)

Tags: php

I need to upload the image to a server and store to the directory created by PHP using current timestamp. Below is the relevant part of the code, but not working as expected, it's not creating a folder as well it's not printing to the console. What could be the issue?

**Edit:**

Modified php based on below comment

**upload.php**

```
  <?php 
//get unique id
$up_id = uniqid(); 
?>

<?php

//process the forms and upload the files
if ($_POST) {

//specify folder for file upload

$user = "user";


//console.log("debug.......");
 echo "debug.......";

if (!file_exists("/var/www/Scan")) {
    mkdir("/var/www/Scan", 0777, true);
}

$folderName = date("Y-m-d") . "_" . date("h_i_sa") . "_" . $user;
if (!file_exists("/var/www/Scan/$folderName")) {
    mkdir("/var/www/Scan/$folderName", 0777, true);
}

$folder = "/var/www/Scan/$folderName"; 

//specify redirect URL
$redirect = "upload.php?success";

//upload the file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

//do whatever else needs to be done (insert information into database, etc...)

//redirect user
header('Location: '.$redirect); die;
}
//

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Upload your file</title>

<!--Progress Bar and iframe Styling-->
<link href="style_progress.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--Get jQuery-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--display bar only if file is chosen-->
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
//

//show the progress bar only if a file field was clicked
    var show_bar = 0;
    $('input[type="file"]').click(function(){
        show_bar = 1;
    });

//show iframe on form submit
    $("#form1").submit(function(){

        if (show_bar === 1) { 
            $('#upload_frame').show();
            function set () {
                $('#upload_frame').attr('src','upload_frame.php?up_id=<?php echo $up_id; ?>');
            }
            setTimeout(set);
        }
        //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";

    });
//
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="outPopUp">

<h1 >Upload your file  </h1>



  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">

    <br />
    <br />
    <!--Choose a file to upload<br />-->

<!--APC hidden field-->
    <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" id="progress_key" value="<?php echo $up_id; ?>"/>
<!---->

     <!-- <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="30"/>-->

<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" onclick="myFunction()"  />
    Choose Video
</label>

<!--Include the iframe-->
    <br />

<br />
    <iframe id="upload_frame" name="upload_frame" color= black frameborder="0" border="0" src="" scrolling="no" scrollbar="no" > </iframe>
    <br />
<!---->

<br />

    <input class="btn btn-blue" name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

<br />
<br />
    <?php if (isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
    <span  style="color:#FFFFFF;" id="message" class="notice">Your file has been uploaded.</span>
    <?php } ?>

  </form>
  </div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";

}
/*document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
  //alert('Selected file: ' + this.value);
  var path = this.value;
  var fileName = path.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');
  alert('Selected file: ' + fileName);
  //myFunction(fileName);

};*/

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "`$folder = "/var/www/Scan/'.$folderName"; `" is not concatenating properly; did you mean `$folder = "/var/www/Scan/$folderName"`?

Comment: Yes, the same way, but why no console output.

Comment: Since when did PHP implement `console.log();`? Or dot-notation for that matter...

Comment: `console.log()` is a JavaScript function, not PHP. You can't output to the console with PHP. You can `echo` text which will be output to the browser/terminal

Comment: and if it still doesn't work for you after all that, then your form may be an issue and permissions. So, check for errors.

Comment: Yes `$folder = "/var/www/Scan/$folderName"` not working.

Comment: `<strike>`you have another answer (now deleted); ask them now (which was already established in comments)`</strike>`. I told you what to do; check for errors and post your html form

Comment: Here, give this a whirl `$folder = "/var/www/Scan/$folderName/";` you forgot the trailing slash and bad concatenation. If that doesn't work........ do as I said a couple of times @CodeDezk

Comment: now that answer's been undeleted, *sigh, facepalm*.

Comment: @CodeDezk So, did my comment up there do anything? I'm not getting any feedback here. If I don't know what's working or not, I can't help you anymore than I already tried. Ping me if you want, I'm moving on. I have to go now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for no response for a short, are you available now.

Comment: @CodeDezk for a bit yes. It's lunchtime here soon ;-) and my stomach is growling!

Comment: I can see you online, I will post entire code.

Comment: if your code is too big, make up a pastebin file (with no expiry) and paste the link in your question. I'll see what I can do. Now, did that answer given below not work for you? What about the comments I left also? are you checking for errors via PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - echo your code out here and there and do a var_dump() to see what comes of it. best I can do here for you right now

Comment: I am going to check  var_dump(), I will let you know the result. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think the problem with permission of /var/www/ folder, when I change the directory path to ./scan the directory created.

Comment: which is what I had mentioned earlier ;-) (3 hours+ ago)

Comment: You are right, couldn't check at that time as I was on iftar break :),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a simple example for understanding:

> ```
> <?php
>
> //php content
> if ($_POST) {   //here we are checking $_POST values that $_POST has some values. 
>
>   //specify folder for file upload
>   $tempDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'upload'; //it means make a directory uploads where this php file is kept.
>   if (!file_exists($tempDir)) { // if $tempDir is not there, so it will create that directory.
>       mkdir($tempDir);
>   }
>
>   if(!empty($_FILES))//now checking your uploaded file is not empty
>   {
>       $nm=$_FILES['file']['name']; //here $nm get the name of the file 
>       $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];//$tmp get the temporary file stored path 
>       $mDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .time().$nm; //this your destination path with time+nameof file as a name of file.
>       if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$mDir)) //uploading file to your destination path, if uploaded then it will go in the if scope and echo.
>       {
>           echo "file uploaded with timestamp in uploads folder";
>           //now redirect from here any where
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           echo "fail to upload a file";
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: sure this works, yet all the guy had to do was fix the one line. Which I might add, he's not answering me.

Comment: it will make a uploads directory and then uploads the file with timestamp.

Comment: and console.log() can not be used in php, it can be used only in the <script>Javascriptsss

Comment: I'd also explain your answer, as code-only answers are discouraged. Explain what you did.

Comment: and this is only for your understanding that how we can create folder and how can we store file in that folder with the timestamp+name as a file name